# How to connect action between two view controller?

Tags: ios

I have two view controller in my storyboard.

In first view controller, there is a button-A and it have action-A.
When i press button-A in first view controller, it show image of A in second view controller.

I declare action-A in viewcontroller.h file and implement actionA in viewcontroller.m file.
Then i connect action-A and button-A on First Responder of first view controller.

When i test this App, i click button-A but it didn't enter into action-A.

Where did i make any mistake?
I just start learn iOS and i'm not a professional. 
Please, help me what should i do?

In viewcontroller.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
 IBOutlet UIPageControl *pagecontrol;
 IBOutlet UIImageView *imageview1;
 IBOutlet UIImageView *imageview2;

 UIImageView *tempimageview, *bgimageview;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) UIPageControl *pagecontrol;
@property (nonatomic,retain) UIImageView *imageview1;
@property (nonatomic,retain) UIImageView *imageview2;

- (IBAction) ButtonA_Click:(UIButton *)sender;
```

In viewcontroller.m

```
@implementation ViewController

@synthesize imageview1;
@synthesize imageview2;
@synthesize pagecontrol;

- (IBAction) ButtonA_Click:(UIButton *)sender;
{
 [imageview1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MyImage.jpg"]];
 tempimageview = imageview2;
 [imageview1 setHidden:NO];
 [imageview2 setHidden:YES];
}
```

Comment: Please be a bit more specific about what your code _should_ do and what it actually _does_. Also some code snippets would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand is that you want to have two individual views controlled by their view controllers. Therefore you don't want two ImageViews in each of them, but only one.

Bear in mind, that you'll have two individual objects aka view controllers. Your code looks more, that you expect to have only one, which deals with both views. That doesn't work.

To make this work, the first view controller has to tell the second view controller which image it should use. This either works by

- use a notification sent from the first to the second vc. See [NSNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003701) on how to use `addObserver...` and `postNotification`
- or to have a property of the second vc in the first vc, which you'll set during the creation of the views. In the end you'll need some way, that both view controllers can talk to each other.

Also, please don't declare the outlets private; delete them from the brackets and write:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    UIImageView *tempimageview, *bgimageview;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIPageControl *pagecontrol;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageview1;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageview2;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually, I forget in OOP and I just start learn iOS. Whatever, thanks for your help. I think i need to read more.

Comment: Thanks you. If i make any mistake, please forget me. I am a new user of this site. I need to learn more to understand completely how to use this site. Thanks for your advice and help SAE.